# How to pass data between background.js and popup.js

Tags: javascript, video-capture

I am trying to capture a video of a tab using its ID in the background so that it keeps recording if the popup is closed.

**background.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action == "startRecording") {
    startCapture(message.tabId);
  } else if (message.action == "stopRecording") {
    stopCapture(message.tabId);
  }
});

let mediaRecorders = {};

function createTabsRecorders(tabId, stream) {
  mediaRecorders[tabId] = { recorder: new MediaRecorder(stream), chunks: [] };
}

async function startCapture(tabId) {
  console.log(tabId);

  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    return;
  }

  const mediaStreamId = await chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId(tabId);

  // Get a media stream for the tab's audio and video.
  const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: "tab",
      chromeMediaSourceId: mediaStreamId,
    },
  });

  createTabsRecorders(tabId, mediaStream);

  mediaRecorders[tabId].recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
      mediaRecorders[tabId].chunks.push(event.data);
    }
  };

  mediaRecorders[tabId].recorder.onstop = () => {
    const blob = new Blob(mediaRecorders[tabId].chunks, {
      type: "video/webm",
    });

    // Create a local URL for the blob
    const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Create a download link (anchor tag)
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.style.display = "none";
    a.href = videoURL;
    a.download = "captured_video.webm";

    // Add the link to the document and trigger a click event to initiate the download
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    a.remove();

    // Clear the chunks array
    mediaRecorders[tabId].chunks = [];
  };

  mediaRecorders[tabId].recorder.start();
}
```

**popup.js**:

```
...........
startBTN.addEventListener("click", function () {
  stopBTN.disabled = false;
  startBTN.disabled = true;
  saveButtonState(tab.id, true);
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "startRecording", tabId: tab.id });
});
.........
```

unfortunately this example throws this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

I don't understand if this error means that it can't see .onMessage in my background.js so I am a little confused, can someone help me?